# What is the difference between specifying the parameter between brackets and without it?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I would like to know the difference between calling .filter() with a parameter surrounded by brackets () and calling it with a parameter without those as shown in the following example:

```
    this._notifications.filter((notif) => {})

    this._notifications.filter(notif => {})
```

Comment: Your don't need *parentheses* if you only have one parameter. You need them if you have more than one.

Comment: None really, but you might be forced to use bracket, if syntax requires it.

Comment: `You need them if you have more than one` or less than one :p - exactly one (simple) parameter and you don't need `()` ...

Comment: by the way, look up arrow function documentation for a full rundown on what you're talking about

Comment: @JaromandaX True, I usually just use `_ =>` instead if I don't have any parameter since I'm lazy, hence my omission ^^

Comment: but there's also `(({propertyname}) =>` syntax, it's a single parameter :p ... also `((...rest) =>` needs `()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference at all actually. It's just a syntactic sugar to remove the parenthesis when you have only one argument to pass into the arrow function. But, you **MUST** put the parenthesis when you have multiple arguments to pass. Also, this question is not related particularly to the  `.filter` method only but to any method of any object in JS that takes a callback function as a parameter or, even while assigning some arrow function to a JS variable like:

```
var a = (b) => console.log(b);
```

is same as:

```
var a = b => console.log(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

there is no difference, it is just preference.. both will work provided there is only one argument.. but if there are more than one.. you need to enclose it with parens like this:

```
this._notifications.filter((notif, someProps) => {}
```

as a rule, my teacher would always tell me to enclose it with parenthesis, even if it has only 1 arg.. so, boils down to preference actually. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

TLDR; There is no difference if only one parameter is passed. When more than one are passed (or no params are passed) use the parans

Quoting relevant parts from the spec:

```
  ArrowFunction[In, Yield] :
    ArrowParameters[?Yield] [no LineTerminator here] => ConciseBody[?In]
  ArrowParameters[Yield] :
    BindingIdentifier[?Yield]
    CoverParenthesizedExpressionAndArrowParameterList[?Yield]
```

Where `CoverParenthesizedExpressionAndArrowParameterList`

```
  CoverParenthesizedExpressionAndArrowParameterList[Yield] :
    ( Expression[In, ?Yield] )
    ( )
    ( ... BindingIdentifier[?Yield] )
    ( Expression[In, ?Yield] , ... BindingIdentifier[?Yield] )
```

So you see, both just `BindingIdentifier` and `CoverParenthesizedExpressionAndArrowParameterList` (which is the syntax with parans) are perfectly valid syntax. The first one refers to the case with single parameters and the second one refers to when multiple parameter are passed or no params are passed.

Comment: ... or less than 1

Comment: Thanks. Made the change :)